# FTP file size and downloaded file size checking

Tags: bash, curl

I have a task in which I want to handle error occurred in FTP downloading,
For which I used `wget` command to download a file from FTP and once the download is complete, compare downloaded filesize with FTP file size.

For that, I have the code as follow. 
My question is this the correct method?

fetch file details from the server and extract only number from the return var

```
FileSizeOnServer=curl --max-time 10 -u $FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD --head $FTP_Path 2>&1 | grep "Content-Length:"
echo "Present File Size Details:" $FileSizeOnServer

FTP_File_Size=${FileSizeOnServer#*: }
echo "FTP_File_Size:$FTP_File_Size"
```

fetch only size of local file size

```
DownloadedFileSize=`stat -c %s /home/pi/Desktop/ABCD.txt`
echo "DownloadedFileSize:$DownloadedFileSize"
```

compair local and ftp file size

```
if [ "$DownloadedFileSize" -eq "$FTP_File_Size" ]; then
    echo "Size matched"
else
    echo "File Size doesn't match Start Downloading again"
fi
```

The code looks as follows

```
FileSizeOnServer=curl --max-time 10 -u $FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD --head $FTP_Path 2>&1 | grep "Content-Length:"
echo "Present File Size Details:" $FileSizeOnServer

FTP_File_Size=${FileSizeOnServer#*: }
echo "FTP_File_Size:$FTP_File_Size"

DownloadedFileSize=`stat -c %s /home/pi/Desktop/ABCD.txt`
echo "DownloadedFileSize:$DownloadedFileSize"

if [ "$DownloadedFileSize" -eq "$FTP_File_Size" ]; then
    echo "Size matched"
else
    echo "File Size doesn't match Start Downloading again"
fi
```

Comment: Does this code work?  If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its tests if you have some) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Yes code works fine. But as i am new to shell scripting i am not confident.

Comment: It sounds like [codereview.se] is the right place to get the feedback you want, then.

Comment: Hmm. Hard to believe `FileSizeOnServer=curl --max-time 10....` is really doing what you think. Try checking your code at https://shellcheck.net before posting to CodeReview. Also, please read [help] and [mcve] before posting more Qs here. Good luck.